# In terms of angular should i assign functions to services and app wide variables to factories?

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, factory

So let's say I have the following:

**factory**

```
var currentRecordId
```

**controller**

```
$scope.currentRecord = MyService.getCurrentRecordById(MyFactory.currentRecordId)
```

**service**

```
//define getCurrentRecordById
```

My thinking is that the factory holds all variables (and therefore state) that I need across multiple controllers and my service holds functions which I will need across multiple controllers.

The reasoning being that functions in factories will compute the function once and return the value where as a service will call the function.

Is this an expected way of going about placing common variables and common functions in a angular app or is there a better way.

I do not want to place functions or variables in the rootscope because I do not need these functions and variables for every controller only a subset.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as few resources state it over the internet ([here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/07/07/service-vs-factory-once-and-for-all.html), for instance), there is very few differences (not to say only One) between factories and services. And those differences are implementation differences, AngularJS design choices. For the developers using the framework in an ES5 environment, this is the exact same thing.

So you don't need to split attributes and methods in factories and services. You can define ONE factory/service with a private attribute and define a public getter, or define both public (if you need the attribute as a "app wide variable").

Sharing data between controllers is a job suiting Services (/factories) perfectly.

Comment: I agree with you, but for storing global values I would go with angular.value() recipe

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even know about this Recipe. I'm quite new to AngularJS. Yet, looking at the doc, it feels like it's made for "read-only" values, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed! But the syntax doesn't look very natural to me. I'd rather go for a service with a getter and setter. Maybe it's just me! Yet it's a pretty useful Recipe, thanks again!!

Comment: Sure, I've used service for storing values aswell... it's a good solution.